# Link Object File in Visual Studio LNK2019

Tags: c++, c, object-files

right now I am trying to use a function of an object file in my visual studio project.
The object file is native compiled and generated outside the visual studio project and now the final goal would be to call a function of it in my .cpp file.
The object file is named test.obj in this case.
If I try to include it I get the following linker errors

> Fehler  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __cdecl std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QEAA@H@Z)" in Funktion ""class std::ctype const & __cdecl std::use_facet >(class std::locale const &)" (??$use_facet@V?$ctype@D@std@@@std@@YAAEBV?$ctype@D@0@AEBVlocale@0@@Z)".   FlexDll C:\Users\ldeppler\Desktop\FLEXDLLNEW\FlexDll\test.obj

I get about 40 of these errors

> Fehler  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_Getctype" in Funktion ""public: struct _Ctypevec __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Getctype(void)const " (?_Getctype@_Locinfo@std@@QEBA?AU_Ctypevec@@XZ)".    FlexDll C:\Users\ldeppler\Desktop\FLEXDLLNEW\FlexDll\test.obj

My object file is compiled by this command:

> cl /EHsc /c /MT /I. test.cpp

Comment: You need to provide more details...

Comment: your main function, the one you link test.obj with it, is it also a c++ file?

Comment: Is you Visual Studio's version older than the one used to compile test.obj ?

Comment: I am not thinking that he got the obj file from Visual Studio @JoëlHecht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things can cause [LNK2019 error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx).

But most probably either appropriate function declarations are not exist or not spelled correctly in your current project.

You can have the appropriate function declarations by including the header file that is used to create object file or pasting the them at the beginning of your cpp files where the functions are used.